# coffeescript fat arrow access not parent 'this'

Tags: jquery, coffeescript, arrow-functions

This works great

```
    @nav.on 'click', ->
        _this.mover _this.nav.index $(@)
```

but I am wondering if I can use a fat arrow instead like this

```
    @nav.on 'click', =>
        @mover @nav.index $(????)
```

but what would I put in place of `@` that will result in `this` instead of `_this`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

jQuery event handlers get an event object as an argument and that event object has [`target`](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/) and [`currentTarget`](http://api.jquery.com/event.currentTarget/) properties:

```
@nav.on 'click', (ev) =>
    @mover @nav.index $(ev.currentTarget)
```

You might want one of the [other properties of `ev`](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/) depending on your specific circumstances.

Comment: You should probably use `ev.currentTarget` if your `@nav` entries have nested elements – the descendants won't be found in the collection.